# makeSceneTransitionAnimation between two recyclerViews working only in reverse

Tags: android, android-animation

*In short :*

Creating shared element activity transition between fragment with recyclerView onClick opening activity with another recylcerView does not trigger transition.

However, using `supportFinishAfterTransition();` to close the opened Activity **does** trigger the animation correctly (it goes backwards to the previous activity).

Also, creating the shared elements *outside* the recyclerView will cause the animation to work properly at every case (both forwards and backwards on finish) - therefore my code must be correct.

*Viewholder with OnClickListener that opens the Activity - simplified to reduce useless code.*

```
public class StatsViewHolder extends WebStatsViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        protected TextView vTitle;
        protected ImageView vPicture;

        public StatsViewHolder (View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            vTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.stats_title);
            vPicture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.stats_picture);

            vTitle.setClickable(true);
            vTitle.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition(), v.getRootView());
            }
        }
    }
```

*Clicking title opens new activity. - animation does not trigger unless I put the target outside of recycler*

```
mAdapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new MySteamWebStatsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position, View parent) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Details.class);
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), parent.findViewById(R.id.stats_picture), "stats_picture");
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I'm just stupid, leaving this up in case somebody makes the same mistake.

In target `recyclerView` I was using Picasso to load drawable - the time Picasso needed to load image was exactly time animation took and therefore it didn't show up. That's also reason why the animation worked in reverse - the image was already cached.

**How to solve the issue :**

Wait until the image is loaded - I called this in `onCreate`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    postponeEnterTransition();
}
```

Request callback from Picasso when image is loaded

```
Picasso.with(this).load(mapObject.getDrawable()).transform(new CircleTransform()).fit().centerCrop().into(detailPicture, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    scheduleStartPostponedTransition(detailPicture);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });
```

Start the animation

```
private void scheduleStartPostponedTransition(final View sharedElement) {
        sharedElement.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        sharedElement.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        startPostponedEnterTransition();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: What if the network is not available? My application hangs.

Comment: Yes, you should never use code like this on network downloads - Use only on images you are sure that are available immediately or almost instantly. You can also try catching your error in `onError()` callback of picasso or use a placeholder.